# swift- Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift

CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'RxAlamofire' from project 'Pods')
cd /Users/annanovas/Desktop/OfficeProject/partha/bds-ma-ios/Pods
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name RxAlamofire -Onone -enable-batch-mode -enforce-exclusivity=checked @/Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RxAlamofire.SwiftFileList -DDEBUG -D COCOAPODS -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -g -module-cache-path /Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options -embed-bitcode-marker -enable-testing -index-store-path /Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Index/DataStore -swift-version 5 -I /Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire -F /Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire -F /Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire -F /Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RxSwift -parse-as-library -c -j6 -output-file-map /Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RxAlamofire-OutputFileMap.json -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RxAlamofire.swiftmodule -Xcc -I/Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire.build/RxAlamofire-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire.build/RxAlamofire-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire.build/RxAlamofire-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire.build/RxAlamofire-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire/include -Xcc -I/Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RxAlamofire-Swift.h -import-underlying-module -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/annanovas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BDS-MA-cvhuwklfttcxblggixgkwwcpsbww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/RxAlamofire.build/unextended-module-overlay.yaml -working-directory /Users/annanovas/Desktop/OfficeProject/partha/bds-ma-ios/Pods

Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: have you tried to clean your project and delete the derived data, then build?

Comment: are you using Mac M1 or something?

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1: Delete Derived Data From Xcode Preferences

### Step 2: Clean Your Project (Shift + Command + K)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).